# Почему при определителе матрицы равном нулю, она не имеет обратной матрицы?

Tags: математика, матрицы

Почему при определителе матрицы равном нулю, она не имеет обратной матрицы?

Comment: При чём тут программирование? Как связаны определители прямой и обратной матриц?

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что он не имеет отношения к программированию

Comment: Глубокий вопрос :) - потому, что матричное уравнение A*X=E (Е-единчная матрица) не имеет  решения, когда матрица А имеет линейно зависимые строки, а значит ее определитель равен 0. Это все равно что пытаться решить уравнение 0*х=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну, как вариант - например, потому что [определитель произведения двух квадратных матриц равен произведению определителей сомножителей](http://stu.sernam.ru/lect_alg.php?id=69). Имея

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

получаем, что

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но если

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

то о какой обратной матрице вообще может идти речь? Если ее определитель просто не существует?